# Занимает ли поле память в структуре, если структура ограничена в длине байт?

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, interop

Мне очень важно понять, будет ли размер структуры изменен, если я ее допустим определили ее так:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, Size = 12324)]
public unsafe struct GammaControl
{
    public Rgb Scale;
    public Rgb Offset;

    public Rgb[] GammaCurve
    {
        get
        {
            Rgb* realDataPtr = GammaCurvePtr;
            Rgb[] arrayResult = new Rgb[1025];

            for (int i = 0; i < 1025; i++)
            {
                arrayResult[i] = *(realDataPtr + i);
            }

            return arrayResult;
        }
    }

    public Rgb* GammaCurvePtr
    {
        get
        {
            fixed (GammaControl* thisPtr = &this)
            {
                return (Rgb*) IntPtr.Add((IntPtr) thisPtr, 24);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

И не затрутся ли `GammaCurvePtr` и `GammaCurve` если я передам указатель на структуру в неуправляемый код, где после `Offset` определен массив `Rgb[1025]` в который записываются данные?

Comment: я не спец, но `GammaCurvePtr` - геттер - это  ведь метод, а не данные, как он может затереться?

Comment: В том то и дело, я не знаю куда кладется код метода, но мне важно это узнать. Т.к. у структуры как вы заметили, просто указан размер, но данных нет.

Comment: если мне не отшибает память, то методы привязаны к типу, а не к экземпляру, но я могу ошибаться.

Comment: @tym32167: и Вы абсолютно правы! Легче всего достать из памяти виртуальные методы. За статикой и «обычными» instance-методами придётся лезть в дебри структуры EEClass

Comment: @tym32167 все верно.

Comment: Если вы пишите на свежем C#, обязательно отметьте вашу чудо-структуру как `ref struct`, то есть как структуру разрешенную для размещения только на стеке! Потому что при попытке разместить ее на куче будет гонка между свойством GammaCurve и сборщиком мусора...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> И не затрутся ли GammaCurvePtr и GammaCurve если я передам указатель
>   на структуру в неуправляемый код, где после Offset определен массив
>   Rgb[1025] в который записываются данные?

Ответ - не затрутся. По крайней мере потому, что атрибут *StructLayoutAttribute*, согласно документации, задает взаимное расположение и **размер полей (данных)** структуры. А ваши `GammaCurvePtr` и `GammaCurve` в конечном счете являются методами структуры.

**UPD.**

> Где хранятся методы?

Сами методы структуры хранятся в *секции кода сборки*, и оттуда они загружаются при первом запуске сборки. **Методы являются частью типа, а не экземпляра типа**. А память под переменные метода уже выделяется либо на стеке, либо в куче. Они не будут затирать память, выделенную под вашу структуру.

Comment: Не могли бы вы дополнить ответ тем, где хранятся методы, будь то структура. или класс?

Comment: @LLENN обновил вопрос